# Attempt import error: 'MDBSideNav' is not exported from 'mdbreact'

Tags: reactjs, mdbreact

import { MDBInput, MDBNavbar, MDBNavbarNav, MDBNavItem, MDBNavLink, MDBDropdown, MDBDropdownToggle, MDBDropdownMenu, MDBDropdownItem, MDBIcon, MDBSideNavItem, MDBSideNavCat, MDBSideNavNav, MDBSideNav, MDBContainer } from "mdbreact";

Answer (score 0):

You should try with the newest version of MDB React. They resolved this problem.